# Git History extension not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-history

I've used the very nice Git History extension before in VS Code, but currently when I click its button or call it up from the command palette, nothing happens. All other git functions are working fine.  I just uninstalled and reinstalled the extension, to no avail.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: I did not face the problem. I am just asking in order to help. Did you create a file called `.git` with `git init` command? This file holds your local git history, and also did you set your git **username, email and password**?

Comment: I do have a .git folder that appears to have basically the same contents as the .git folder of another project where the git history extension is working. So, it's definitely something to do with the project. The project I'm having problems with definitely has a normal functioning repo, and I can call `git log` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. Uninstall the extension, close the vscode and open it. then, install the extension again. It sounds crazy but It worked for me!